# Ford focus 2011 -- 6006E CD RDS EON

Tags: ford, audio, focus, jack

Someone already installed a jack for mp3 on a 6006E CD RDS E-O-N radio?
it's possible with this radio or i need to change radio?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: Is what possible?  I understand there is a jack installed on a radio.  What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 6006E is a CD player with an in-unit storage of up to six CD discs. It does not have an AUX input and it will not play MP3. If it essential for you to be able to play MP3 then you will be looking at a differant radio/CD player which is MP3 compatable. An alternative would be to use a gadget along the lines of an iPod FM transmitter. You could then tune your radio into the FM transmitter, which you can load with your MP3 data/music and play the content through your cars system.